# Numerical Integration in Laplace domain

Tags: numerical-integration

I need to calculate two different integrals containing a Bessel function in the Laplace domain. I have tried different kinds of quadrature but didn't have any luck. I don’t know how to help Mathematica along to treat the Laplace variable (s) in the equations:

@ RolfMertig, thanks to the details. I have successfully added the inversion algorithm for time domain. But the results do not look very good and take a very long time to compute… This is really bugging me out! And I still couldn't find a way to compute this efficiently…

```
eq1[(s_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[BesselK[0, Sqrt[u^2 + s]], {u, 0, 40}]; 
eq2[(s_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[BesselK[0, Sqrt[u^2 + s]], {u, 0, -10}]; 
eq3[(s_)?NumericQ, (n_)?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[BesselK[0, Sqrt[(-Log[t])^2 + ((n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s)]]*
         Cos[n*Pi*((50 + (15 - Log[t]/Sqrt[(n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s])*
           Cot[30*Degree])/100)]*(1/t), {t, 0, -10*Sqrt[(n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s]}]; 
eq4[(s_)?NumericQ, (n_)?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[BesselK[0, Sqrt[(-Log[t])^2 + ((n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s)]]*
         Cos[n*Pi*((50 + (15 - Log[t]/Sqrt[(n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s])*
           Cot[30*Degree])/100)]*(1/t), {t, 0, 40*Sqrt[(n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s]}]; 
PD[s_] = (1/(s^(3/2)*100*Sin[30*Degree]))*(eq1[s] - eq2[s]) + 
         (2/(s*100*Sin[30*Degree]))*Sum[(1/Sqrt[(n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s])*
         Cos[n*(Pi/2)]*(eq3[s, n] - eq4[s, n]), {n, 1, 10}]; 
SetOptions[NIntegrate, Method -> "ClenshawCurtisRule", 
  WorkingPrecision -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 2]; 
Ni = 8; 
V[i_, NN_] = (-1)^(i + NN/2)*Sum[(k^(1 + NN/2)*(2*k)!)/((i - k)!*
       k!^2*(-i + 2*k)!*(-k + NN/2)!), {k, Floor[(1 + i)/2], Min[i, NN/2]}]; 
PD1[tD_] = (Log[2]*Sum[PD[(i*Log[2])/tD]*V[i, Ni], {i, 1, Ni}])/tD; 
LogLogPlot[{PD1[y], y*Derivative[1][PD1][y]}, {y, 1, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Black}, {Dashed, Black}}, Frame -> True]
```

I'm not sure if I’m missing something obvious or computing these equations in a completely rough way. Can anyone provide an insight?

Comment: Is there any reason why you absolutely have to use Clenshaw-Curtis? Your `eq1` seems to be fine, but I'd have done something like `eq1[s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[BesselK[0, Sqrt[u^2 + s]], {u, 0, -10}, Method -> "ClenshawCurtisRule"]` myself.

Comment: @J.M., the reason for Clenshaw-Curtis is that I found a reference that suggests the chebyshev polynomials as integration procedure for these computations. But it seems that no other method can work these equations as well...

Comment: You should have edited your question instead of posting a new answer. In any event: Your `PD[]` has calls to `eq1` and others when they should be `eq1[s]`; also your functions being numeric preclude constructions like `PD1'[y]`; you will have to implement a separate method for the derivative if you need it.

Comment: `eq3`and `eq4` have "n" it it, so you should use `eq3[s_?NumericQ,n_?NumericQ]` for these and call them in `PD` with 2 parameters. And you should use `PD[s_]:=...`. Than you can call e.g. `PD[2]` and get a value (`0.0182218 + 0.0011354 I`). But the integrals seem to convert badly, because you'll get a bunch of messages, so you can't trust this value.

Comment: @BrunoRangel As J.M. already pointed out: your Derivative[1][PD1][y] does not make sense. You need to program it (and the derivatives for eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4). Maybe you can fix this?

Answer (score 4):

This will calculate hundred PD in a few minutes, depending on your computer:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
eq1[(s_)?NumericQ] := (Print["eq1[",s//InputForm,"]"]; NIntegrate[BesselK[0, Sqrt[u^2 + s]], {u, 0, 40}]); 
eq2[(s_)?NumericQ] := (Print["eq2[",s//InputForm,"]"]; NIntegrate[BesselK[0, Sqrt[u^2 + s]], {u, 0, -10}]); 
eq3[(s_)?NumericQ, (n_)?NumericQ] :=  (Print["eq3[",s//InputForm,",",n, "]"]; 
    NIntegrate[BesselK[0, Sqrt[(-Log[t])^2 + ((n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s)]]*
         Cos[n*Pi*((50 + (15 - Log[t]/Sqrt[(n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s])*
           Cot[30*Degree])/100)]*(1/t), {t, 0, -10*Sqrt[(n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s]}]
); 
eq4[(s_)?NumericQ, (n_)?NumericQ] :=  (Print["eq4[",s//InputForm,",",n,"]"]; 
  NIntegrate[BesselK[0, Sqrt[(-Log[t])^2 + ((n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s)]]*
         Cos[n*Pi*((50 + (15 - Log[t]/Sqrt[(n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s])*
           Cot[30*Degree])/100)]*(1/t), {t, 0, 40*Sqrt[(n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s]}]
); 
PD[s_] := (1/(s^(3/2)*100*Sin[30*Degree]))*(eq1[s] - eq2[s]) + 
         (2/(s*100*Sin[30*Degree]))*Sum[(1/Sqrt[(n^2*Pi^2)/100 + s])*
         Cos[n*(Pi/2)]*(eq3[s, n] - eq4[s, n]), {n, 1, 10}]; 

ParallelEvaluate@
SetOptions[NIntegrate, Method -> "ClenshawCurtisRule", WorkingPrecision -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> 2]; 

ParallelTable[PD[i],{i,100}]

]
```

Comment: Sorry, I might have mixed up this answer by accepting a suggested review by @Bruno Rangel. How the review improved the answer was unclear so I rolled it back. Could you please make sure that no harm was done?

Comment: @IstvánZachar, it's correct. Nothing changed.

Comment: @RolfMertig, thanks to the details. I have successfully added the inversion algorithm for time domain. But the results do not look very good and take a very long time to compute… This is really bugging me out! And I still couldn't find a way to compute this efficiently…

Comment: @IstvánZachar that gave me 15 points less ...

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 variables in your equations, but you integrate over one only. So the integrand will never be numeric (always a "s" in eq1). This is why `NIntegrate` yields the error. It you will give an numerical value for s, e.g, `s=2` then `NIntegrate` will give you a numerical result.

`NIntegrate` always complains, if the result is not a number.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but the problem is that I don't think that I can give the Laplace variable "s" a value. Because eventually I'll need it for a numerical inversion to time domain...

Comment: @Bruno: then you should try the suggestion I gave in my previous comment...

Comment: Hey J.M.: Thanks for the suggestion! I have used, but Mathematica still can't give me an expression to put into the inversion algorithm…  I’m posting my codes bellow, so you can have a clear idea of the problem. I still can't figure it out what it's going wrong…